# How to avoid cycle error in golang. I just need in func arguments

Tags: dictionary, go, struct

I saw related problems in stackoverflow, they advised to use the interface. But I don't know how to integrate it into my code...

I have main function in

> project.com/exec

```
package main
import (
    appNames "project.com/exec/namemodel"
    appKafka "project.com/exec/kafka"
)
func main(){
    namesMap := make(map[string]*appNames.Name)
    nameObj := appNames.Name{}
    nameObj.FullName = "Alexander Lebowsky"
    nameObj.Recieve()
    namesMap["Alexander Lebowsky"] = &nameObj
    appKafka.ListenChars(nameObj)
    nameObj.SendName()
}
```

In name model

```
package namemodel
import(
    appKafka "project.com/exec/kafka"
)
type Name struct {
    FullName          string
    Characteristics   string
    NameChannel       chan string
}
func (nameobj *Name) SendName(){
    appKafka.Send(nameobj.Name)
}
func (nameobj *Name) Recieve(){
    for{
         nameobj.Characteristics = <- NameChannel
    }
}
```

In kafka package

```
package kafka
import(
    "github.com/segmentio/kafka-go"
    appNames "project.com/exec/namemodel"
)
func Send(name string){
    conn, err := kafka.DialLeader(context.Background(), "tcp", "localhost:8888", "test", 0)
    _, err = conn.WriteMessages(
        kafka.Message{Value: []byte(name)},
    )
}
func ListenChars(namesMap map[string]*appNames.Name){
    conf := kafka.ReaderConfig{Brokers: []string{"localhost:8888"}, Topic: "test1",}
    reader := kafka.NewReader(conf)
    for {
         m, err := reader.ReadMessage(context.Background())
         var model JsonModel
         err = json.Unmarshal(m.Value, &model)
         name := model["Name"]
         if nameObj, ok := namesMap[name]; ok {
             nameObj.NameChannel <- model["chars"]
         }
    }
}
```

Please don't care about error validation. I did it in my actual code, it is sample code. Please help with "import cycle not allowed". How to improve my code? I know I can create method in exec/namemodel, that can recieve through argument, but I need to receive through channel. Nevertheless it will not avoid problem with cyclic. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don’t make tiny packages. It realy is that simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You kafka and namemodel packages are closely coupled. You should consider merging the two. If there are reasons not obvious to us that prevents you from merging them, you can expose the `Send` functionality to namemodel package:

```
package namemodel

var Sender func(string) error

func (nameobj *Name) SendName(){
    Sender(nameobj.Name)
}
```

Then, either in `main` or in an `init()` function in kafka package, set the Sender function in namemodel package

```
package main

func main() {
   ...
   namemodel.Sender=kafka.Send
   ...
}
```

Comment: It is interesting. But It looks unusual... Is there a more elegant way? Because importing other module functions and sending it to another, seems unusual for me. Or is it usual for golang? I am a newbie, so understand me, please))

Comment: @NurislomRakhmatullaev, the alternative (and preferred) solution is in the answer also: merge the two packages that depend on each other into one package.

Comment: @NurislomRakhmatullaev, it is not unusual. Function variables are no different from other variables in Go. You could use interfaces as well, but with a single function, this is usually easier. If you don't have any other reason to keep the two packages separate, merge them, or do not include functionality like `Send` in your models.